# Pycharm coding help needed

Tags: pandas, csv

I am working on a csv file in pycharm. I have successfully imported the file and need to know:

1. what packages to install
2. what functions can help me remove the unwanted columns
3. what function can convert the strings to values.

I tried using pandas, openpyxl, matplotlib, scripy, delete function, numpy.

Comment: Your question is too vague and thus [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we're not here to give you a tutorial. Read the documentation(s), follow tutorials, make mistakes and try to solve them **by yourself**, only then come here if you're really stuck with a **specific question**. This is not against you, we just need focused questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter which IDE you use.

1. read csv:
2. drop columns:
3. convert string:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv("exams.csv") 
   df = df.drop(columns=['math_score', 'reading_score']) 
   df ['education'] = df ['education'].astype(str)
   ```